# ArcPy geocode address geocoding syntax

Tags: arcpy, geocoding

Currently I am trying to run a "custom" composite address locator through script and I cannot seem to figure out the proper syntax.  I can run the geocoder through the Arc Geocoder Tool (Runs Manually) but I cannot seem to get it working in the script.

In the tool the address inputs are as follows:

- Street or Intersection:
- City or Placename:
- State:
- ZIP Code:
- ZIP4

```py
addrFld = "AddrAdded"
lkCity1Fld = "MapCity"
stateFld = "State"
geo_flds = "Street or Intersection {0};City or Placename {1};State {2};ZIP Code <None>;ZIP4 <None>".format(addrFld, lkCity1Fld, stateFld)
locator = r"SomeDrive\Composite_Parcels"
arcpy.GeocodeAddresses_geocoding(in_table, locator, geo_flds, out_fc)
```

Receiving Error: `ERROR 000010: Geocode addresses failed. Failed to execute (GeocodeAddresses).`

- The input table runs through the tool
- The the address locator exists
- The output location is the same as it is in the tool
- Running: Arc 10.4.1
- License: Advanced

Comment: Have you tried just using ArcMap/ArcCatalog to geocode the table manually? That isn't a good error returned but it makes me think the Geocoder/Locator might be a issue.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by works in the Arc Tool will edit the text to say manually runs.

Comment: Have you tried using model-builder to just do a quick set of the same steps; then export that model to py? sometimes that can help you see where some idiosyncrasy that the initial export can highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting the the GeocodeAddresses_geocoding tool into model builder and then converted the model to a python script to find the proper syntax.

Replaced the geo_flds line with the following:

```py
geo_flds = "Street AddrAdded VISIBLE NONE;City City VISIBLE NONE;State State VISIBLE NONE;ZIP <None> VISIBLE NONE;ZIP4 <None> VISIBLE NONE"
```